# ZFS allocation algorithm

Tags: solaris, zfs

I'm looking for a way to know which algorithm ZFS is using to find free blocks.
By default there are two algorithms:

1. Best Fit
2. First Fit

These are automatically changed once a threshold is passed regarding free metaslabs available on the zfs pool.
After searching a long way and finding that we can tune the metaslab % before switching the algorithm, I really want to find which one is currently in use.

Any thoughts on know-how on this?

Comment: It was described in Jeff Bonwick's blog: [ZFS Block Allocation](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/en/entry/zfs_block_allocation), but there is no information there about best fit/first fit. Where did you get this information?

Comment: Ended up by finding something in My Oracle Support but it is no longer valid for recent releases as the code was changed.

Comment: can you post id of My Oracle Support document? Thanks.

Comment: Here goes: When is setting the tunable metaslab_df_free_pct appropriate? (Doc ID 1503020.1)